# Sum up similar plus and minus values rows to output a clean result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `transaction` table where I require to generate a summary.

```
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|transaction_id | student_id | payment_id | amount | action |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|             1 |          1 |           1|    100 |      1 |
|             2 |          1 |           2|     50 |      1 |
|             3 |          1 |           3|      0 |      1 |
|             4 |          1 |           4|     25 |      1 |
|             5 |          1 |           5|    200 |      1 |
|             6 |          2 |           1|    100 |      1 |
|             7 |          2 |           2|     50 |      1 |
|             8 |          2 |           2|    -50 |      0 |
|             9 |          2 |           4|    -25 |      0 |
|            10 |          2 |           5|   -200 |      0 |
|            11 |          3 |           2|     75 |      1 |
|            12 |          3 |           4|    -25 |      0 |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

(action : 1 = Payment, 0 = Cancellation )

I can get a summary of transactions by following query as mentioned below.

```
SELECT payment_id, amount, COUNT(amount) AS student_count, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
  FROM transaction t
    GROUP BY payment_id, amount;
```

The result is.

```
+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
| payment_id | amount | student_count | total_amount |
+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
|          1 |    100 |             2 |          200 |
|          2 |    -50 |             1 |          -50 |
|          2 |     50 |             2 |          100 |
|          2 |     75 |             1 |           75 |
|          3 |      0 |             1 |            0 |
|          4 |    -25 |             2 |          -50 |
|          4 |     25 |             1 |           25 |
|          5 |    200 |             1 |          200 |
|          5 |   -200 |             1 |         -200 |
+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
```

But, in summary I want to sum up each similar amount plus and minus values to keep it clean. So, the requirement is an output like below summing up plus and minus values to show the result.***If they sum up to zero then that row doesn't require to be shown.***

```
+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
| payment_id | amount | student_count | total_amount |
+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
|          1 |    100 |             2 |          200 |
|          2 |     50 |             1 |           50 |
|          2 |     75 |             1 |           75 |
|          3 |      0 |             1 |            0 |
|          4 |    -25 |             1 |          -25 |
+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
```

It's highly appreciated if somebody could help out to achieve this in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the (updated) data that you have supplied, I think this query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a28e7/9)) should produce what you want:

```
SELECT 
  payment_id,
  ABS(amount) AS amount,
  ABS(SUM(IF(action=1,1,-1))) AS student_count,
  SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM transaction
GROUP BY payment_id, ABS(amount)
HAVING total_amount != 0 OR amount = 0
```

Output:

```
payment_id  amount  student_count   total_amount
1           100     2               200
2           50      1               50
2           75      1               75
3           0       1               0
4           25      1               -25
```

If you want the amount for `payment_id` 4 to be negative (to match `total_amount`), change the third line of the query to (updated [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a28e7/15))

```
  ABS(amount)*IF(SUM(amount)>0,1,-1) AS amount,
```

That will give

```
4           -25     1               -25
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. It doesn't work Nick as if there's only minus values they don't appear. Plus, free(0) values also don't appear.

Comment: You can resolve the minus values by changing `total_amount > 0` to `total_amount != 0`. You said in your question though that you didn't want 0 totals to appear.  If you do just remove the`HAVING` clause completely.

Comment: Thanks again. I think lack of proper data might not have helped you to properly understand the problem. So, I updated data. So, as there can be different amounts for same payment_id GROUP BY only by payment_id doesn't seem to be working. Further, you might have misunderstood my comment. It's only if sum up of plus and minus values. Eg. 5->200

Comment: See my edit. I think it does what you want now. Minus sums and free sums appear, and payments are grouped by id and amount to allow for different amounts for the same payment_id

Comment: Thank you very much. That's almost perfect Nick. If you could make amount appear as -25 in last row that would make it complete.

Comment: Are you sure -25 is the correct value for amount in that row? The first payment_id of 4 has a value of 25. Anyway, if you are, see my edit for a way to get that result.

Comment: Now it's perfect. Thanks a lot Nick.

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate the data on just the payment_id.

```
SELECT 
  payment_id,
  MAX(amount) amount,
  (COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) - SUM(amount<0)) student_count,
  SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM `transaction`
GROUP BY payment_id;
```

See [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60670/5).

Comment: Thanks for the support. There's a problem in student_count. For 50 it should be only 1 student.

Comment: Thanks again. I think lack of proper data might not have helped you to properly understand the problem. So, I updated data. So, as there can be different amounts for same payment_id GROUP BY only by payment_id doesn't seem to be working.